# Latency in Websocket

Tags: arduino-nano, wifi, nodemcu, web-server

I am using Websocket, for a communication from my mobile phone to a NodeMCU, and transmitting 4 channel, data, through 4 different Websocket Ports.
the NodeMCU control code is here:

```
// ============ By Pritam Pagla ============ //
// The Only Websocket Program is attached within master branch

// NodeMCU SIDE


#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>     // Preferably use ArduinoJson 5.x, as StaticJsonBuffer object is not defined in further versions
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include<WebSocketsServer.h>

#include "index_NodeMCU_Test1.h";   // Complete Webpage

SoftwareSerial s(D6,D5);          // Rx as D6 and Tx and D5

int16_t throttle_Val = 0;
int16_t yaw_Val = 0;
int16_t pitch_Val = 0; 
int16_t roll_Val = 0;

uint8_t num; 
WStype_t type; 
uint8_t *payload; 
size_t length;

//WiFi Connection configuration
const char *ssid = "PriCopter";       // Can choose these anything one wants
const char *password = "01234567";

WebSocketsServer Twebsocket = WebSocketsServer(9001);     
WebSocketsServer Ywebsocket = WebSocketsServer(9002);
WebSocketsServer Rwebsocket = WebSocketsServer(9003);
WebSocketsServer Pwebsocket = WebSocketsServer(9004);

ESP8266WebServer server(80);


//================================================


void handleRoot() {
 String s = MAIN_page; //Read HTML contents
 server.send(200, "text/html", s); //Send web page
}

//================================================
//            Setup
//================================================
 
void setup() {
s.begin(115200);
Serial.begin(115200);
 delay(100);
  
  //Setup the NodeMCU as an AP
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password, 1, false, 1);    //Use NodeMCU as an access point

  //If connection successful show IP address in serial monitor
  IPAddress IP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(IP);

  //Initialize Webserver
  server.on("/",handleRoot);
  
  server.begin();  
  Twebsocket.begin();
  Ywebsocket.begin();
  Rwebsocket.begin();
  Pwebsocket.begin();

}
 
void loop() {
 StaticJsonBuffer<100> jsonBuffer;
 JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.createObject();

 server.handleClient();
 Twebsocket.loop();
 Ywebsocket.loop();
 Rwebsocket.loop();
 Pwebsocket.loop();
 
 Twebsocket.onEvent(ThrottleEvent);
 Ywebsocket.onEvent(YawEvent);
 Rwebsocket.onEvent(RollEvent);
 Pwebsocket.onEvent(PitchEvent);
 
 Serial.print("Throttle:  "); Serial.print(throttle_Val);
 Serial.print("   Yaw:  "); Serial.print(yaw_Val);
 Serial.print("   Pitch:  "); Serial.print(pitch_Val);
 Serial.print("   Roll:  "); Serial.print(roll_Val);
 
  root["throttle"] = throttle_Val;
  root["yaw"] = yaw_Val;
  root["roll"] = pitch_Val;
  root["pitch"] = roll_Val;
  
 root.printTo(s);
 Serial.println("   (Sent)");
}


void YawEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t *payload, size_t length){
  if (type == WStype_TEXT){
      yaw_Val = (int16_t)strtol((const char*) &payload[0], NULL, 10);
  }
}

void ThrottleEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t *payload, size_t length){
  if (type == WStype_TEXT){
      throttle_Val = (int16_t)strtol((const char*) &payload[0], NULL, 10);
  }
}

void RollEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t *payload, size_t length){
  if (type == WStype_TEXT){
      roll_Val = (int16_t)strtol((const char*) &payload[0], NULL, 10);
  }
}

void PitchEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t *payload, size_t length){
  if (type == WStype_TEXT){
      pitch_Val = (int16_t)strtol((const char*) &payload[0], NULL, 10);
  }
}
```

and requiring Webpage details is as:

```
const char MAIN_page[] PROGMEM = R"=====(<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = 'en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=950, height=420 initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
    content="ie=edge"/>
    <title>Drone Remote</title>
    <style>
    body{
      background-color: #333;
      color: 'black';
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      min-height: 100vh;
      margin:0;
    }
    #canvasL{
      background: #f0f0f0;
      border-radius: 5x
    }
    #canvasM{
      background: #f0f0f0;
      border-radius: 5px
    }
    #canvasR{
      background: #f0f0f0;
      border-radius: 5px
    }
    
    #source{
      display: none;
    }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvasL" width="450" height="420"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvasM" width="50" height="420"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvasR" width="450" height="420"></canvas>

    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="" id="source"/>
    <script>
    const canvasL = document.getElementById('canvasL');       // Object for left canvas
const Lctx = canvasL.getContext('2d');

const canvasM = document.getElementById('canvasM');       // Object for Middle canvas
const Mctx = canvasM.getContext('2d');

const canvasR = document.getElementById('canvasR');       // Object for Right canvas
const Rctx = canvasR.getContext('2d');

const LcenterX = (canvasL.width / 2);    // Marking centre for left Joystick
const LcenterY = (canvasL.height / 2);
const RcenterX = (canvasR.width / 2);    // Marking centre for Right Joystick
const RcenterY = (canvasR.height / 2);
const McenterX = (canvasM.width / 2);    // Marking centre for Middle Portion
const McenterY = (canvasM.height / 2);


var Tsocket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':9001/');
var Ysocket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':9002/');
var Psocket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':9003/');
var Rsocket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':9004/');

const image = document.getElementById('source');

var throttle_Val = 0;
var yaw_Val = 0;
var pitch_Val = 0;
var roll_Val = 0;

const throttle = "t";
const yaw = "y";
const pitch = "p";
const roll = "r";

const LJoyStickBall = {         // defining left joystick as an object
  w: 60,
  h: 60,
  x: LcenterX,
  y: LcenterY+195,
  speed: 1,
  dx: 0,
  dy: 0
};
const RJoyStickBall = {         // defining right joystick as an object
  w: 60,
  h: 60,
  x: RcenterX,
  y: RcenterY,
  speed: 1,
  dx: 0,
  dy: 0
};

function drawLeftCenterBall(){      //Drawing the Left Joystick ball
  Lctx.drawImage(image, LJoyStickBall.x-30, LJoyStickBall.y-30, LJoyStickBall.w, LJoyStickBall.h);
}
function drawRightCenterBall(){      //Drawing the Right Joystick ball
Rctx.drawImage(image, RJoyStickBall.x-30, RJoyStickBall.y-30, RJoyStickBall.w, RJoyStickBall.h);
}

function LnewPos() {                    // changing position for keyboard activity
  LJoyStickBall.x += LJoyStickBall.dx;
  LJoyStickBall.y += LJoyStickBall.dy;

  LdetectBoundary();
}

function RnewPos() {                    // changing position for keyboard activity
  RJoyStickBall.x += RJoyStickBall.dx;
  RJoyStickBall.y += RJoyStickBall.dy;

  RdetectBoundary();
}

function LdetectBoundary(){             // defining the boundary for the LeftJoystickCenterBall
  // Left side
  if (LJoyStickBall.x < LcenterX-195) {
    LJoyStickBall.x = LcenterX-195;
  }

  // Right side
  if (LJoyStickBall.x > LcenterX+195) {
    LJoyStickBall.x = LcenterX+195;
  }

  // Top side
  if (LJoyStickBall.y < LcenterY-195) {
    LJoyStickBall.y = LcenterY-195;
  }

  // Bottom side
  if (LJoyStickBall.y > LcenterY+195) {
    LJoyStickBall.y = LcenterY+195;
  }
}

function RdetectBoundary(){             // defining the boundary for the LeftJoystickCenterBall
  // Left side
  if (RJoyStickBall.x < RcenterX-195) {
    RJoyStickBall.x = RcenterX-195;
  }

  // Right side
  if (RJoyStickBall.x > RcenterX+195) {
    RJoyStickBall.x = RcenterX+195;
  }

  // Top side
  if (RJoyStickBall.y < RcenterY-195) {
    RJoyStickBall.y = RcenterY-195;
  }

  // Bottom side
  if (RJoyStickBall.y > RcenterY+195) {
    RJoyStickBall.y = RcenterY+195;
  }
}


function drawDesigns(){               // 4 Convrntric circles and 2 crossed st lines for better interface
  Lctx.beginPath();
  Lctx.lineWidth = 2.5;
  Lctx.moveTo(LcenterX, LcenterY-195);    // Crossing lines on left
  Lctx.lineTo(LcenterX, LcenterY+195);
  Lctx.moveTo(LcenterX-195, LcenterY);
  Lctx.lineTo(LcenterX+195, LcenterY);
  Lctx.arc(LcenterX, LcenterY, 195, 0, Math.PI * 2);   //Concentric circles on Left
  Lctx.arc(LcenterX, LcenterY, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  Lctx.arc(LcenterX, LcenterY, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  Lctx.arc(LcenterX, LcenterY, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  Lctx.stroke();

  Rctx.beginPath();
  Rctx.lineWidth = 2.5;
  Rctx.moveTo(RcenterX, RcenterY-195);    // Crossing lines on Right
  Rctx.lineTo(RcenterX, RcenterY+195);
  Rctx.moveTo(RcenterX-195, RcenterY);
  Rctx.lineTo(RcenterX+195, RcenterY);
  Rctx.arc(RcenterX, RcenterY, 195, 0, Math.PI * 2);   //Concentric circles on Right
  Rctx.arc(RcenterX, RcenterY, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  Rctx.arc(RcenterX, RcenterY, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  Rctx.arc(RcenterX, RcenterY, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  Rctx.stroke();
}
function clearScreen(){             // Clearing the LeftCanvas and RightCanvas on every loop of the Animation
  Lctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasL.width, canvasL.height);
  Rctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasR.width, canvasR.height);
}

function ConsoleOUT(a,b,c,d){
   throttle_Val = (405-a);
   yaw_Val = (b-225);
   pitch_Val = (210-c);
   roll_Val = (d-225);
  console.log('Throttle: '+throttle_Val+'    Yaw: '+yaw_Val+'    Pitch: '+pitch_Val+'    Roll: '+roll_Val);
}

function LeftUpdate(){
  clearScreen();                                //Left Joystick
  drawDesigns();
  drawLeftCenterBall();
  drawRightCenterBall();
  LnewPos();
  RnewPos();
  ConsoleOUT(LJoyStickBall.y,LJoyStickBall.x,RJoyStickBall.y,RJoyStickBall.x);
  requestAnimationFrame(LeftUpdate);
  
}
function RightUpdate(){                                 //Right Joystick
  clearScreen();
  drawDesigns();
  drawLeftCenterBall();
  drawRightCenterBall();
  LnewPos();
  RnewPos();
  ConsoleOUT(LJoyStickBall.y,LJoyStickBall.x,RJoyStickBall.y,RJoyStickBall.x);
  requestAnimationFrame(RightUpdate);
}

function LmoveUp() {                          // For KeyboardActivity 
  LJoyStickBall.dy = -LJoyStickBall.speed;
}

function LmoveDown() {
  LJoyStickBall.dy = LJoyStickBall.speed;
}

function LmoveRight() {
  LJoyStickBall.dx = LJoyStickBall.speed;
}

function LmoveLeft() {
  LJoyStickBall.dx = -LJoyStickBall.speed;
}
function RmoveUp() {
  RJoyStickBall.dy = -RJoyStickBall.speed;
}

function RmoveDown() {
  RJoyStickBall.dy = RJoyStickBall.speed;
}

function RmoveRight() {
  RJoyStickBall.dx = RJoyStickBall.speed;
}

function RmoveLeft() {
  RJoyStickBall.dx = -RJoyStickBall.speed;
}





canvasL.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){         // 'touchstart' event in LeftCanvas
       e.preventDefault();    
       canvasL.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
              var touchobj = e.touches[0]; // reference first touch point for this event
              LJoyStickBall.x = touchobj.pageX;
              LJoyStickBall.y = touchobj.pageY;
              sendData(throttle,405-LJoyStickBall.y);
              sendData(yaw,LJoyStickBall.x-225);
              }, false)
   }, false)

   canvasL.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){            // 'touchend' event in LeftCanvas
       e.preventDefault();
       LJoyStickBall.x = LcenterX;
       sendData(yaw,0);
    }, false)

canvasR.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){         // 'touchstart' event in RightCanvas
       e.preventDefault(); 
       canvasR.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
              var touchobj = e.touches[0]; // reference first touch point for this event
              RJoyStickBall.x = touchobj.pageX - (canvasR.width + RJoyStickBall.w);
              RJoyStickBall.y = touchobj.pageY - RJoyStickBall.h;
              sendData(pitch,210-RJoyStickBall.y);
              sendData(roll,RJoyStickBall.x-225);
              
          }, false)
   }, false)

   canvasR.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){            // 'touchend' event in RightCanvas
       e.preventDefault();
       RJoyStickBall.x = RcenterX;
       RJoyStickBall.y = RcenterY;
       sendData(pitch,0);
       sendData(roll,0);
      }, false)



  function sendData(a,b){

    if(a == throttle){
      Tsocket.send(b);
    }
    if(a == yaw){
      Ysocket.send(b);
    }
    if(a == roll){
      Rsocket.send(b);
    }
    if(a == pitch){
      Psocket.send(b);
    }
    
    // switch(a){


    //   case throttle:
    //     Tsocket.send(b);
    //     break;
    //   case yaw:
    //     Ysocket.send(b);
    //     break;
    //   case roll:
    //       Rsocket.send(b);
    //       break;
    //   case pitch:
    //       Psocket.send(b);
    //       break;
    //   default:
    //     console.log('Interruption Occured.')
    // }
  }



  document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {        // When certain key is pressed down
    if (e.key == 'ArrowRight') {
      LmoveRight();
      sendData(yaw,LJoyStickBall.x-225);
    } if (e.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
      LmoveLeft();
      sendData(yaw,LJoyStickBall.x-225);
    } if (e.key == 'ArrowUp') {
      LmoveUp();
      sendData(throttle,405-LJoyStickBall.y);
    } if (e.key == 'ArrowDown') {
      LmoveDown();
      sendData(throttle,405-LJoyStickBall.y);
    }
    if(e.key == 'w'){
      RmoveUp();
      sendData(pitch,210-RJoyStickBall.y);
    }
    if(e.key == 's'){
      RmoveDown();
      sendData(pitch,210-RJoyStickBall.y);
    }
    if(e.key == 'a'){
      RmoveLeft();
      sendData(roll,RJoyStickBall.x-225);
    }
    if(e.key == 'd'){
      RmoveRight();
      sendData(roll,RJoyStickBall.x-225);
    }
  });
   document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {        // When certain key is released 
    if (
      e.key == 'ArrowLeft' ||
      e.key == 'ArrowRight' ||
      e.key == 'ArrowUp' ||
      e.key == 'ArrowDown' ||
      e.key == 'w' ||
      e.key == 's' ||
      e.key == 'a' ||
      e.key == 'd'
    ) {
      LJoyStickBall.dx = 0;
      LJoyStickBall.dy = 0;
      RJoyStickBall.dx = 0;
      RJoyStickBall.dy = 0;
      LJoyStickBall.x = LcenterX;
      RJoyStickBall.x = RcenterX;
      RJoyStickBall.y = RcenterY;
      sendData(yaw,0);
      sendData(pitch,0);
      sendData(roll,0);
    }
  });

  LeftUpdate();
  RightUpdate();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

)=====";
```

Now, I am new to Web based projects and clearly new to Websockets. In the beginning, i used single websocket port and transmitted the data of the four channels as JSON file, but differentiating the data in 4 different channels, increased the speed slighly, but still one problem is consistent throughout, i.e. after a few seconds, (30-35), it starts to achieve latency, and it stays untill the page is not refreshed again.
Can someone please suggest any solution for this, as I am using this for controlling my drone, therefore, any unnecessary latency can be dangerous.

For further information, you can see detailed description and similar codes in this [repo](https://github.com/Pritam-Pagla/Drone-Control).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your WebSocket server listens on port 81, whereas your client connects to 9000–9003. Are you sure the HTML you posted matches the sketch just above it? Please, make sure the elements of your question are consistent with one another.

Comment: Ohh, I'm really sorry for that, actually I made several versions  of this project, and previously I did with, one websocket port, and actually I mistakenly pasted it from that project. I'm just making it right.

Comment: now you can check!

Comment: Having 4 servers isn't neccessary. Does the latency happen from time to time and does recover or does the latency remain high? I currently have a similar issue with the WebsocketsClient from that repo

Answer (score 1):

Not really a proper answer, but a few ideas that hopefully could help
you debug the issue:

- I doubt using multiple WebSocket servers really helps, as you end up
  adding more context switching, i.e. you have to loop through all of
  them even when they have no data to process.
- `SoftwareSerial` tends to be really slow, as it blocks execution of
  the sketch while it is sending. You may try to disable it, at least
  while you troubleshoot this latency issue.
- Calling `Serial.print()` on every loop iteration is also going to slow
  the sketch down until it is no faster than the serial port. Try to
  print only once in a while, or only when things actually change.
- Both Firefox and Chrome have “developer tools” which should help you
  diagnose the problem. At the very least you should be able to see
  whether the slowdown comes from the server or from the client.

Comment: No, i just used SoftwareSerial for the SBUS between NodeMCU and Nano, that has nothing to do with websocket, and without that, it still gives the same problem.